# Next.js Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, hydration

Don't know what is causing this error?

If I remove the following code, the error doesn't get shown.

Why is this part of the code causing this error and how can I resolve it?

```
      <div className="relative flex flex-col items-center pt-[85.25%] sm:pt-[56.25%] md:pt-[56.26%]">
        <ReactPlayer
          className="absolute top-0 left-0"
          url={`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u5-CF_k0KK0&list=RDu5-CF_k0KK0&start_radio=1&ab_channel=TumpyGFX`}
          width="100%"
          height="100%"
        />
      </div>
```

Comment: It's most likely the `ReactPlayer` component. Try dynamically importing that component using [`next/dynamic`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr) with `ssr: false`.

Comment: see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76051589/3073272

Answer (score 9):

my solution：

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
```

then

```
const TestimonialCard = dynamic(() => import('./TestimonialCard'), { ssr: false })
```

hope to help you!

Comment: Do I have to do this for every components that gives me this error? I have  hundreds of them

Answer (score 4):

Ensure the HTML in your application is valid. Does the code snippet you included exist inside a `<p>` tag? This is usually the problem. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).