# Nextjs 13 Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, local-storage

I am using next 13.1.0.
I have a ContextProvider that sets a light and dark theme

```
'use client';
import { Theme, ThemeContext } from '@store/theme';
import { ReactNode, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

interface ContextProviderProps {
  children: ReactNode
}

const ContextProvider = ({ children }: ContextProviderProps) => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState<Theme>('dark');

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
    if (storedTheme === 'light' || storedTheme === 'dark') {
      setTheme(storedTheme);
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem('theme', theme);
    }
    // added to body because of overscroll-behavior
    document.body.classList.add(theme);
    return () => {
      document.body.classList.remove(theme);
    };
  }, [theme]);

  const toggle = () => {
    const newTheme = theme === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light';
    setTheme(newTheme);
    localStorage.setItem('theme', newTheme);
  };

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, toggle }}>
      {children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { ContextProvider };
```

I use it in my root layout

```
import '@styles/globals.scss';
import { GlobalContent } from '@components/GlobalContent/GlobalContent';
import { ContextProvider } from '@components/ContextProvider/ContextProvider';
import { Inter } from '@next/font/google';
import { ReactNode } from 'react';

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] });

interface RootLayoutProps {
  children: ReactNode
}

const RootLayout = ({ children }: RootLayoutProps) => {
  return (
    <html lang="en" className={inter.className}>
      <head />
      <body>
        <ContextProvider>
          <GlobalContent>
            {children}
          </GlobalContent>
        </ContextProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
};

export default RootLayout;
```

And I consume the theme value in my GlobalContent

```
'use client';
import styles from '@components/GlobalContent/GlobalContent.module.scss';
import { GlobalHeader } from '@components/GlobalHeader/GlobalHeader';
import { GlobalFooter } from '@components/GlobalFooter/GlobalFooter';
import { ThemeContext } from '@store/theme';
import { ReactNode, useContext } from 'react';

interface GlobalContentProps {
  children: ReactNode
}

const GlobalContent = ({ children }: GlobalContentProps) => {
  const { theme } = useContext(ThemeContext);
  return (
    <div className={`${theme === 'light' ? styles.lightTheme : styles.darkTheme}`}>
      <GlobalHeader />
      <div className={styles.globalWrapper}>
        <main className={styles.childrenWrapper}>
          {children}
        </main>
        <GlobalFooter />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export { GlobalContent };
```

I get the error

```
Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
```

[image]

[React docs error link](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=418)

I don't understand why I am getting this error because I am accessing `localStorage` inside my `useEffect`, so I expect the HTML generated on the server to be the same with the client before the first render.

How can I solve this error?

Comment: have you analyzed the exact HTML difference?  (should be part of the error message)

Comment: The error message says nothing about the HTML difference. I am starting to think this is a nextjs 13 bug as 13 still is not ready for production. The error message also shows up randomly. Maybe 1/10 times?

Comment: I've added an image showing the error I'm getting in my console along with the react docs error link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have made a workaround that solves the issue for now at the cost of giving up SSR.

By using a [dynamic import](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import) on my `ContextProvider`, I disable server-rendering and the error is gone. As a bonus, the flashing issue from my default dark theme to my light theme saved on `localStorage` is gone. But I give up the benefits of SSR. If someone finds a better solution, please do share.

```
import '@styles/globals.scss';
import { GlobalContent } from '@components/GlobalContent/GlobalContent';
import { Inter } from '@next/font/google';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import { ReactNode } from 'react';

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] });

interface RootLayoutProps {
  children: ReactNode
}

// Fixes: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
const DynamicContextProvider = dynamic(() => import('@components/ContextProvider/ContextProvider').then(mod => mod.ContextProvider), {
  ssr: false
});

const RootLayout = ({ children }: RootLayoutProps) => {
  return (
    <html lang="en" className={inter.className}>
      <head />
      <body>
        <DynamicContextProvider>
          <GlobalContent>
            {children}
          </GlobalContent>
        </DynamicContextProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
};

export default RootLayout;
```

This solution does not disable SSR site wide. I added a new test page with the following code

```
async function getData() {
  const res = await fetch('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character', { cache: 'no-store' });
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
  }

  return res.json();
}

export default async function Page() {
  const data = await getData();

  return (
    <main>
      {data.results.map((c: any) => {
        return (
          <p key={c.id}>{c.name}</p>
        );
      })}
    </main>
  );
}
```

After running `npm run build`, I can see that the test page is using ssr

[image]

On checking the response for the test page, I can see the HTML response

[image]

Comment: did you disable ssr site wide? Cant see how you disabled it.

Comment: I disabled ssr only on my `DynamicContextProvider` by passing `ssr: false` to the dynamic import option in the code above. I've also edited my answer to show that SSR on individual pages is still possible with my solution.

Comment: This is not an ideal way

Answer (score 16):

For Next.js 13, return jsx once the component is `mounted`

```js
function Component() {
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    setMounted(true);
  }, []);

  if (!mounted) return <></>;
  // write rest of your code
}
```

Comment: This one fixes the issue

Comment: this is a hack . we shouldn't have to do this in every component

Comment: hi, where can i add this code. I'm trying to use it with Remix. but it's not working

Answer (score 7):

ran into similar issue when i was adding this Navbar component into RootLayout in layout.tsx in Next.js 13.

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
       <Navbar />
      <body className={font.className}>
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

I changed above code and instead added Navbar inside body tag and it fixed the issue.

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={font.className}>
        <Navbar />
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Comment: The NavBar should be inside the body tag anwyay.

Comment: yes. that was my issue. should have added Navbar inside the body from the beginning

Answer (score 1):

I solved the error just by dynamically importing the default export of **ContextProvider** like this in **_app.tsx** . I'm also persisting context state in **localStorage** and it works without a problem .

**_app.tsx**

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
 
const TodoProvider = dynamic(
  () => import("@/util/context").then((ctx) => ctx.default),
  {
    ssr: false,
  }
);

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <TodoProvider>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </TodoProvider>
  );
}
```

**context.tsx**

```
import React, {
  useState,
  FC,
  createContext,
  ReactNode,
  useEffect,
} from "react";

export const TodoContext = createContext<TodoContextType | null>(null);

interface TodoProvider {
  children: ReactNode;
}

const getInitialState = () => {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    const todos = localStorage.getItem("todos");
    if (todos) {
      return JSON.parse(todos);
    } else {
      return [];
    }
  }
};

const TodoProvider: FC<TodoProvider> = ({ children }) => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState<ITodo[] | []>(getInitialState);
  const saveTodo = (todo: ITodo) => {
    const newTodo: ITodo = {
      id: Math.random(),
      title: todo.title,
      description: todo.description,
      status: false,
    };
    setTodos([...todos, newTodo]);
  };
  const updateTodo = (id: number) => {
    todos.filter((todo: ITodo) => {
      if (todo.id === id) {
        todo.status = !todo.status;
        setTodos([...todos]);
      }
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
    }
  }, [todos]);

  return (
    <TodoContext.Provider value={{ todos, saveTodo, updateTodo }}>
      {children}
    </TodoContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default TodoProvider;
```

Comment: Does `updateTodo` work as intended? `setTodos([...todos])` is given the original `todos` and not what is filtered. Maybe the code below helps.

const updateTodo = (id: number) => {
  const updatedTodos = todos.map((todo: ITodo) => {
    if (todo.id === id) {
      return { ...todo, status: !todo.status };
    }
    return todo;
  });
  setTodos(updatedTodos);
};

Answer (score 1):

For those who might encounter this issue because of using a `popover` component, i.e.

```
  <Popover open={open}>
    <PopoverTrigger>
      ...
```

This is caused by invalid Html tag nesting. The fix is to use the `asChild` prop.

Forexample;

```
  <Popover open={open} onOpenChange={setOpen}>
            <PopoverTrigger asChild>
                <Button
                    variant="outline"
                    size="sm"
                    role="combobox"
                    aria-expanded={open}
                    aria-label="Select a store"
                    className={cn("w-[200px] justify-between", className)}
                >
```

Credits to AissaSemaoui's input [here](https://github.com/shadcn-ui/ui/issues/419#issuecomment-1667444044)

Answer (score 0):

For ShadCn, the `ThemeProvider` tag should be under `html` and `body` tags

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was using nextjs v14 and nexui v2.

I had to put my providers just inside the body tag on the root component.
That solved it for me.

@/app/layout.tsx

```
export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {

  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions)
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <Providers session={session}>
          {children}
        </Providers>
      </body>

    </html>
  );
}
```

@/app/providers.tsx

```
export function Providers({ children, session }: { children: React.ReactNode, session: any }) {
    return (
        <SessionProvider session={session}>
            <NextUIProvider>
                {children}
            </NextUIProvider>
        </SessionProvider>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The root layout is defined at the top level of the app directory and applies to all routes. This layout is required and must contain html and body tags, allowing you to modify the initial HTML returned from the server.

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        {/* Layout UI */}
        <main>{children}</main>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

and by default, layouts in the folder hierarchy are nested, which means they wrap child layouts via their children prop. You can nest layouts by adding layout.js inside specific route segments (folders). so just make it like this:

```
export default function DashboardLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return <section>{children}</section>
}
```